# Nginx with Wordpress not showing template 404 for certain file types

Tags: 404-error, server, nginx

I am using Nginx on Ubuntu to host a Wordpress site and everything is working great except certain file types return the Nginx 404 rather than the Wordpress template 404.

For example:
http://www.sbbic.org/something.zip
shows the Nginx 404 page.

While http://www.sbbic.org/2014/06/17/free-english-khmer-dictionary-mac-osx-download2
shows the template 404 page.

What am I missing in my configuration of Nginx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received a response with code that fixed the issue from [rtcamp.com](https://rtcamp.com/support/topic/some-404-errors-handled-by-nginx-others-by-wordpress/)

Add this code to the nginx site configuration for the domain has the issue with not all 404 requests being handled by Wordpress:

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
}
```